# Regex Only Obtaining the first element -Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
import re

message = '13-45-33-19-29-8'

phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d|\d-\d\d|\d-\d\d|\d-\d\d|\d-\d\d|\d- 
\d\d|\d') 
mo = phoneNumRegex.search(message) 
c = mo.group() 
new = c.replace('-',',')
print(type(new))
listed = list(map(int,new.split(',')))
print(listed)
print(type(listed))
```

When I run the code, it only outputs [13] when it should be the entire list with all the numbers in message. Does this have something to do with the \d? I used the character | in order catch numbers that were single digit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong function. `search` always returns only the first match. You need `findall`:

```
phoneNumRegex.findall(message) 
#['13', '45', '33', '19', '29', '8']
```

Comment: I tried that. I got the following error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Of course it does not. It _is_ the final answer. A list of numbers. Didn't you want a list of numbers?